# "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" on the second click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a weird problem in javascript alerts in my application. On a button click,  alert displaying with an ok button. **For the second click** , i am getting a sentence with a check box "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" .

I know this a feature of browser. But for all other sites this is displaying after 10th click. For my application this is coming for the second click .Please help.

The alert is coming as a result of ajax call.

```
if (result.message!=null && result.message!=''){
    alert(result.message);
}
```

I found the problem coming only when the time between clicks is less than 4 seconds, Any opinion how to increase this .?

Comment: i don't think there is much you can do here

Comment: Are you creating those alerts in a loop?

Comment: No.. The alert is coming as a result of ajax call..

Comment: can you provide some more code, because normally "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" come after 10 alerts only

Comment: madfriend is right. You cant change the browser settings of the browser on the client's machine. You will have to look at other options for displaying the message.

Comment: I never use `alert`. For development, you should use console output (which has the advantage that you can examine logged objects) or a html-element to log the messages and for Production use a dialog-box (jquery ui).

Answer (score 1):

Most common browser implement such a feature in order to prevent `alert` spam. Use another notification method, for example an [absolute positioned div](http://jsfiddle.net/MxQWJ/).

The [jQuery.UI dialog module](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) could give you some ideas.